# Ruby rspec Mocking a class

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking, rspec2

I have a file with two classes in it.

```
class LogStash::Filters::MyFilter< LogStash::Filters::Base
```

and

```
class LogStash::JavaMysqlConnection
```

`JavaMysqlConnection` has methods `initialize` and `select`. It is in use by the `MyFilter` class, and is used to query the database as you may have guessed.

How do I mock the `initialize` and `select` methods to return nil and an array respectively?

I tried using:

```
before(:each) do
  dbl = double("LogStash::JavaMysqlConnection", :initialize => nil)
end
```

but this did not work, as I am still seeing a communication link failure.

I have rspec version 2.14.8

Thanks in advance.
PS. I am new to Ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following on from Andrey's response, the solution that worked for me was:

```
 before(:each) do
    mock_sql = double(:select=> sql_select_return)
    allow(LogStash::JavaMysqlConnection).to receive(:new).and_return(mock_sql)
end
```

Comment: `each` can be omitted

Answer (score 14):

Bad (working): [Read more as to why exactly it is a bad practice](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/gotchas.html#avoid-using-expect_any_instance_of-or-allow_any_instance_of-in-rspec)

```
allow_any_instance_of(LogStash::JavaMysqlConnection)
  .to receive(:select)
  .and_return([])
```

Good:

```
let(:logstash_conn) { instance_double(LogStash::JavaMysqlConnection) }

allow(LogStash::JavaMysqlConnection)
  .to receive(:new)
  .and_return(logstash_conn)

allow(logstash_conn)
  .to receive(:select)
  .and_return([])
```

[Docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/method-stubs)

[RSpec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#method-stubs)

Comment: Thanks, slightly edited your answer to suit my situation. See my answer.

Comment: Why one solution is better than the other?

Answer (score 2):

Using RSpec [stub_const](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-9/docs/mutating-constants/stub-defined-constant)

```
describe 'No User' do
  let(:user)       { double }
  let(:attributes) { { name: 'John' } }

  before do
    stub_const 'User', instance_double('User', new: user)
  end

  it 'creates user' do
    expect(user).to receive(:update!).with(attributes)

    User.new.update!(attributes)
  end
end
```